# Phone Validation is not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm using this code for validating the phone number:

```
<script>
$("#Phone").keydown(function (e) {
      // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .

      if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+A
        (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
        // Allow: home, end, left, right, down, up
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {



        // let it happen, don't do anything
        return;
      }
      // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
      if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    });


        var val = Phone.value
if (/^\d{11}$/.test(val)) {
    // value is ok, use it
} else {
    alert("Invalid number; must be eleven digits")
    Phone.focus()
    return false
}
</script>
```

I want the user to input only 11 digits and if it doesn't, it alerts user that they have to input 11 digits and sets the value to null.

The problem is, when it alerts that the number is less than 11 digits, it doesn't set the value to null.

Comment: What value should be set null? Where is your code which sets value to null?

Comment: I also tried this.value=""; but it didn't work!

Comment: Whatever the user inputs, If it is not 11 digits, then it should set the value to nothing.

Comment: When you write `this.value=""` - do you know what is `this`? Have you tried `Phone.value=''`?

Comment: Thanks, it worked! but I found another problem! If the user press tab button, the alert will show and then sets the value to null, but if the user clicks on the next field, it does nothing! why?

Answer (score 0):

I know you're asking for a JS solution but this can be done with the new attributes in html5

```
<input type="tel" pattern="[0-9]{11}" placeholder="Your 11 digit phone number..." required/>
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/7owhrssr/

Comment: Well, I gotta admit, this a much easier and lighter solution!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This code can help you, cause may you have problem with regex

```
        var regex =/^\d+$/;
if (regex.test(val)) {
        alert('value is ok, use it');
    }else{
alert('Invalid number; must be eleven digits');
Phone.focus()
    return false}
```

Comment: why I tested it, its worked fine what its problem??!!